# In Yii2, how do I use init command to create index.php in a different directory?

Tags: php, yii2

I am using the advanced application on shared hosting. I have the following folder structure.[image: Shared hosting folder structure] To keep things 'clean' I put all the Yii2 related files in their own directory on the server (in this case under `yii2-advanced-dashboard`) so it is obvious what is what on the shared hosting and in case I need to have other separate applications on the same hosting. I have followed the [tutorial](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/topic-shared-hosting.md) about Yii2 advanced on shared hosting.

My Question is, what do I need to do so that I can run the `./init` command and have Yii2 create the `index.php` file under `public_html/dashboard`? I feel like I should be able to probably configure the behavior using perhaps `createSymlink` under `environments/index.php` but there is not a lot of information out there on this. Hope it all makes sense. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You must connect to the server and write this command there. For example, there is a ssh protocol for this. Your terminal in the ide has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but not quite what I mean. I know how to run `./init` and have the files created. But I want them created in specific directories not the default.

Comment: Then you need to make changes in the folder [environments](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-environments.md)

Comment: Are you able to supply anything more specific for the change relating to the index.php file I want created in a specific directory? Thanks!